# BLAST: can't find reference file in db

Tags: blast

I am trying to run the standalone ncbi-blast-2.2.29+ on my machine (Mac) but get this error message when running blastx (or blastn) with my database:

```
No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [db/viral.1.1.genomic] in search path [~/Users/KK/ncbi-blast-2.3.0+/Virus::]
```

The way I run it:

```
blastn -query input.fasta -out out.blast.txt -db db/viral.1.1.genomic
```

My working directory is ~/Users/KK/ncbi-blast-2.3.0+/Virus and there is a  sub-directory db (~/Users/KK/ncbi-blast-2.3.0+/Virus/db) and db has viral.1.1.genomic.phr, viral.1.1.genomic.pin, viral.1.1.genomic.pnd, viral.1.1.genomic.pni, viral.1.1.genomic.pog, viral.1.1.genomic.psd, viral.1.1.genomic.psi, viral.1.1.genomic.psq, viral.1.1.genomic.fasta. and I made all these files using this command line

```
makeblastdb -in viral.1.1.genomic.fasta -out viral1.1.genomic -dbtype prot -parse_seqids
```

I just don't know why I keep getting error message saying no alias or index file found. I have read other similar questions posted by others but don't seem finding answer to my problem. And I try other tblast and blastx and both of them return similar error except it said protein database instead of nucleotide

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly you need to create the index-file separately. But also pay attention between building nucleotide and/or protein dbs and than search then with the wrong BLAST n/p engin. So 2004. I assume you fixed it and reconstructed your DB the rightway by now?